# How to make a widget with components sized correctly for home screen column space

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to make an Android widget where the components are sized to match the icon size of the home screen, but after looking and looking I simply can't find a way to do this. I have two phones that are both 411dp wide, but one has a 5 column home screen and the other 4 columns, so the icons (home screen columns) are different widths and I'm having trouble designing a widget that looks good on both.

My resizable widget has three components, 2 of which should always be homescreen icon sized and another that can be any size, or not present at all. The widget is always only one row tall. Here's what it should look like going from 5 columns to 1:

12223

1223

123

13

3

And here's how it would work with 4 columns:

1223

123

13

3

Components 1 and 3 should always be the width of an icon on the homescreen (except when component 1 is zero width). Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution it to override onAppWidgetOptionsChanged event in your app widget provider. Then you can filter the relevent components for each view.
For example:

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    int width = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int height = newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

    // Perform some logic
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the `width` variable will contain the exact width of a homescreen column at that point? In dp?

Comment: So this gets me the width of the widget, which is not what I'm looking for. I need the width of a minimum size one column widget.

Comment: Do you want to convert dp to cells ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I want to know the width of a cell in dp so I can size my widget component to fit precisely into one cell. In my experience, the width can vary somewhere from ~60 to ~75 dp, depending on the width of the screen and the number of cells made available in that width.